# How is insertMany different to collection.insert in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I scouted around to find the right solution for inserting a large amount of documents to MongoDB using Mongoose.

My current solution looks like this:

```
MongoClient.saveData = function(RecordModel, data, priority, SCHID, callback){
    var dataParsed = parseDataToFitSchema(data, priority, SCHID);
    console.log("Model created. Inserting in batches.");
    RecordModel.insertMany(dataParsed)
    .then(function(mongooseDocuments) {
         console.log("Insertion was successful.");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        callback("Error while inserting data to DB: "+err);
        return;
    })
    .done(function() {
       callback(null);
       return;
    });
}
```

But it appears to me there are other offered solutions out there. Like this one:
http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/Automattic/mongoose/q/stackoverflow/16726330/mongoose-mongodb-batch-insert

Using `collection.insert`. How is that different to the `Model.insertMany`?

Same goes for update, my previous question: [What is the right approach to update many records in MongoDB using Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742475/what-is-the-right-approach-to-update-many-records-in-mongodb-using-mongoose/38743353#38743353)

Asks how do I update big chunk of data with Mongoose, defined by `_id`. The answer suggests to use `collection.bulkWrite` while I am under impression `Model.insertMany` can do it too.

Comment: You simply cannot do an update operation with `Model.insertMany` because you will be inserting new docs rather than updating existing onces.

Comment: And what is the difference between `Model.insertMany` and `collection.insert`? And why wouldn't they clarify it in official docs?

Comment: These posts may help you with clarification, [What's the difference between insert(), insertOne() and insertMany() method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792649/) and [MongoDB: Bulk insert (Bulk.insert) vs insert multiple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112165/)