# Mongodb in Nodejs, yet another insert performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, insert

I'm learning nodejs and mongodb, just testing insert performance of mongodb on a single low-end laptop using a ramdrive (I'll replace it with redis later) and got result of only 465 inserts per second. Each insert has only x y z values that must not be more than 12 bytes for data.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var client = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:2019/evdb2';
client.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('fail:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('success:', url);
        var collection = db.collection('tablo');
        collection.remove();


        // var bulk = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

        //benchmark insert
        var t = 0;
        t = new Date();
        var ctr = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1024 * 64; i++)
        {
            collection.insert({ x: i + 1, y: i, z: i * 10 }, function (e, r) {
                ctr++;
                if (ctr == 1024 * 64)
                {
                    var t2 = 0;
                    db.close();
                    t2 = new Date();
                    console.log("insert-64k: " + 1000.0 / ((t2.getTime() - t.getTime()) / (1024 * 64)) + " insert/s");
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Node-js command-line:

```
C:\Users\pc> node "....\bench.js"
success: mongodb://localhost:2019/evdb2
insert-64k: 465.62650979054763 insert/s
```

Mongod command-line:

```
2016-11-12T02:02:57.980+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54623 #67 (1 connection now open)
2016-11-12T02:04:07.893+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54630 #68 (2 connections now open)
2016-11-12T02:04:07.895+0300 I NETWORK  [conn67] end connection 127.0.0.1:54623 (1 connection now open)
2016-11-12T02:04:47.976+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54633 #69 (2 connections now open)
2016-11-12T02:04:47.978+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54634 #70 (3 connections now open)
2016-11-12T02:04:47.979+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54635 #71 (4 connections now open)
2016-11-12T02:04:47.981+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54636 #72 (5 connections now open)
2016-11-12T02:06:28.669+0300 I NETWORK  [conn68] end connection 127.0.0.1:54630 (4 connections now open)
2016-11-12T02:06:28.671+0300 I NETWORK  [conn69] end connection 127.0.0.1:54633 (3 connections now open)
2016-11-12T02:06:28.673+0300 I NETWORK  [conn70] end connection 127.0.0.1:54634 (3 connections now open)
2016-11-12T02:06:28.674+0300 I NETWORK  [conn71] end connection 127.0.0.1:54635 (3 connections now open)
2016-11-12T02:06:28.675+0300 I NETWORK  [conn72] end connection 127.0.0.1:54636 (2 connections now open)
```

- Both client and server is same machine so latency must be low isn't it?
- Ramdrive is used for /data/db/ folders so disk must have no bottleneck.
- Also journaling is disabled to let cpu cores have cycles.

**What could be causing this slowdown?** This speed of 465/s increases to 20k/s when replaced with bulk insert.

Here are starting parameters for mongod:

```
C:\....\pc>"C:\....\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod" 
--bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --port 2019 --dbpath m:\data\db 
--quotaFiles 1 --smallfiles --nojournal
```

Nearly 500 inserts per 2 billion cpu cycles is very slow. This means 1 insert per 2M cpu cycles (this is 2 core cpu so it must be 4M cycles per insert because of 100 percent cpu usage)

**Why is there so much difference between bulk and single inserts? Does bulk use some compression technology?** Connection is 100Mbit ethernet cable but information is just pinging back from router without waiting since server and client is same machine, isn't it?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking why there is a performance difference between a large number of individual inserts vs. batched inserts. This is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112165/mongodb-bulk-insert-bulk-insert-vs-insert-multiple-insert . To summarize, repeated individual inserts require repeated interactions/acknowledgements between the app and database. A batched insert requires a single interaction and hands off the work to the database to be completed without constantly checking in with the app.