# Mongo DB write: Which is the better way for multiple upsert?

Tags: java, mongodb

Which is better? bulkWrite with replaceOne operation(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite) or multiple replaceOne(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-replaceone)  operations in a loop? I am using mongo java driver.

Comment: Check out this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112165/mongodb-bulk-insert-bulk-insert-vs-insert-multiple-insert

Comment: Is this true for upsert as well?

Comment: Yes, you can read the @Dummy's answer in the previous link to understand why